# VueJs input file @change does after first call on chrome

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this code

#### HTML:

```
<input id="task-message-input-upload" type="file" ref="file" @change="handleFileUpload($event)" />
```

#### Javascript :

```
data() {
        return {
            uploadedFiles: [],
            showPercentage: false,
            uploadPercentage: 0,
            file: {},

        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleFileUpload(event) {
            this.file = event.target.files[0];
            this.submitFile();
        },
        submitFile() {
            $vm = this;
            this.showPercentage = true;
            let formDataF = new FormData();
            formDataF.append('file', this.file);
            axios.post('/api/v1/savemessagefile',
                    formDataF, {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                        },
                        onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
                                this.uploadPercentage = parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total));
                            }
                            .bind(this)
                    }
                ).then(function(response) {
                    $vm.uploadPercentage = 0;
                    $vm.uploadedFiles.push(response.data);
                })
                .catch(function() {
                    const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                        toast: true,
                        position: 'top-end',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 3000
                    });
                    Toast.fire({
                        type: 'warning',
                        title: '<%=i18n.__('
                        upload_has_been_canceled ')%>'
                    })
                });
        },
    }
```

The problem is that when I click the button for the first time and process the file it works, but when the process is finished, when I click the button for the second time it does not work, the **file** property stays empty on chrome, while on firefox it works.

Here's a gif image showing the issue :
[image: @change bug]

Answer (score 0):

After your submit button, set uploadedFiles to empty array again.